# Is it ok to record a conversation with a professor without their knowledge and can it be used as evidence?

Tags: legal-issues, canada, audio-video-recording, personal-misconduct

If a student is being harassed or expecting to be harassed, can the student record the meeting with the professor without the professor’s knowledge?

Additionally, could this recording be used to create a case or as evidence against or the professor for misconduct either at the college/university level or beyond (e.g. in court)?

Comment: I think you should consult a lawyer, not random people on the internet.

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to explain more about the word "harassed". Thanks

Comment: @user0410 harassment mostly tied to academic performance or conduct of the student. Can include reduction of mark or unjustified grading (lowering GPA or even causing the student to fail a course), bullying (false accusations, dismissal, gaslighting, etc.) or any others.

Comment: I am trying to think of what makes this question specific to academia. That is, what difference would the academic context make, as opposed to a general professional environment. No thoughts so far.

Comment: It can backfire. See "entrapment".

Answer (score 8):

First, the legality varies. Legal in some places, but not in others. A lawyer can give legal advice.

Second, a recording might be ruled inadmissible in any proceedings. The "chain of possession" is an important consideration for evidence in legal proceedings in many places.

Third, and, perhaps more important, recording someone without permission might be perceived by them as a threat, resulting in a dangerous situation. So, I don't recommend this as a course of action.

If you have actually been harassed then report it. If you think you might be harassed, then find a way to avoid the situation in which it might occur or take some action to protect yourself. For example, not meeting the potential harasser privately, especially behind a closed door, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now what about the fact that most schools have an image to uphold, so siding with a professor might be their preferred approach? And if a professor makes false accusations against the student, how should the student protect him/herself?

Comment: Actually, part of that "image to uphold" is (most places) an unwillingness to be associated with monsters. There are a few exceptions, unfortunately, for superstar monsters, but even some of them have crashed and burned. So, it may not be as bleak as you fear. But if you have accusations against you, then a lawyer's advice is probably worth the money unless the normal university process is adequate. The "Dean of Students" or the "Ombuds" might be a useful intermediary. Some places have formal student unions.

Comment: thank you! I’ll keep that in mind.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your third point? I find it very unlikely that a potential perpetrator would behave more aggressively when suspecting they are being recorded. A prospect of having a strong evidence of a wrongdoing is a good reason for not breaking any rules. As I understand, we are talking about a professor in a department, not a mobster on an abandoned street.

Comment: @Buffy is correct that the legality of making a recording depends on the local laws, but there should be no problem with admissibility in evidence. Since you were part of the conversation, you can authenticate the recording by your testimony.

Comment: @Neithea, that depends, also, on the law. I wouldn't want to assume it is true. If it were recorded by a third party and the "chain of possession" were strictly maintained then, yes, but in general, not so obvious. Consult a lawyer. And assume that everything will be challenged.